# Free groups and injective function

Tags: free-groups

We have the following about free groups:

Given a non-empty set $X$, it is possibly to find a group $G$ and a function $\sigma :X\to G$ such that $\sigma (X)$ algebraically generates $G$ and for every group $H$ and every function $f:X\to H$ there exists a homomorphism $\widetilde{f} : G\to H$ such that $\widetilde{f} \circ \sigma = f$.

Now, I want to show that $\sigma$ must be injective.

I'd want to give an injective function $f:X\to G$, because of this there would be a function $\widetilde{f}$ such that $\widetilde{f}\circ \sigma$ is injective.

But is it possibly to prove that cardinality of $X$ is equal or less than cardinality of $G$?

Comment: In your second line it must be "...there exists a **unique** homomorphism..."

Comment: @DonAntonio: not in this case because he assumes $\sigma(X)$ generates $G$.

Comment: So what is your question? Why is $\sigma\,$ injective or why is $\,|H|\le |G|\,$ ?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro, the question's title is about *free* groups...and of course $\,\sigma(X)\,$ generates $\,G\,$, otherwise all this, with or without the free part, is false.

Comment: So if I assume that $\,\langle\,\sigma(X)\,\rangle=G\,$ then automatically $\,G\,$ is free? No, of course. What is then the *additional* condition that must be given?

Comment: No @LuizCordeiro, the *universal property* requires *uniqueness*, just as it is written in your link...

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be any set and $G=\mathscr{F}(X)$ be a free group as you defined, with corresponding function $\sigma:X\rightarrow G$. Let's show that $\sigma$ is injective.

Let $x\neq y$ in $X$, and let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ be any function such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$ (for example, $f(x)=1$, $f(y)=2$ and $f(z)=0$ for any other $z$).
Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a group, there exists a homomorphism $\overline{f}:G\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\overline{f}\circ\sigma=f$, then
$\overline{f}(\sigma(x))=f(x)\neq f(y)=\overline{f}(\sigma(y))$, and therefore $\sigma(x)\neq \sigma(y)$ (since $\overline{f}$ is a function).

We then conclude that $\sigma$ is injective.

Comment: Ohhh, good. Thank you very much, Luiz!